# 'In tone' meaning

Tags: meaning

I've read a text aboat early friendship effect on relationship with siblings. This text is in the book 'Vocabulary for IELTS'. 
In a sentence it says:

> And children who as preschoolers were able to coordinate play with a friend, manage conflicts and keep an interaction positive **in tone** were most likely as teenagers to avoid the negative sibling interaction that can sometimes launch children on a path of antisocial behavior.

I couldn't find 'in tone' anywhere on the Internet!!  What that means here?!

Comment: 'The discussions were positive in tone' = 'The tone of the discussions was positive' (ie they were conducted civilly / probably had a positive outcome).

Comment: positive in [its] tone – in a positive tone

Comment: Thanks guys, your answers were perfect

Comment: The Coneheads say: Maintain Low Tones! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMAUZAFmJTc

Comment: At least one of the comments above is an Answer. Why has no-one supplied an Answer?

Comment: Just look up "tone" in a good dictionary. Commenters have said much without saying what is meant by *tone* in the context. Also @JeremyC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Positive in [its] tone" means "in a positive tone"

The phrase "keep an interaction positive in tone" is just a slightly awkward/literary way of saying ensure that the tone [general character] of any interaction is positive [optimistic, helpful, hopeful].

For example, 'The discussions were positive in tone' = 'The tone of the discussions was positive' (ie they were conducted civilly / probably had a positive outcome).